# How to include ArcGIS Javascript API via CDN with Webpack to work with Stimulus?

Tags: webpack, cdn, blazor, arcgis-js-api, stimulusjs

In the [quick start](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/quick-start/) guide for the ArcGIS javascript api, it has the following sample code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript Hello World App</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView"
    ], function(Map, MapView) {

      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-118.71511,34.09042],
        zoom: 11
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which works great for a simple web page. However, I'm using Blazor (server-side) and I would like to encapsulate the (above) code into a Blazor component. So I hit my first stumbling block - I'm not allowed to add a `<script>` tag inside a Blazor component. That's because the control could be created dynamically at any time. So I thought I'd address the issue with Stimulus instead.

Here's my Blazor component (so far). I have a file called `Map.razor`:

```html
<div data-controller="map"></div>

@code {
    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        var allowRefresh = false;

        return allowRefresh;
    }
}
```

I added the `ShouldRender` method so that the component will be rendered only once (when it's added). And here's what I'm trying to achieve in my Stimulus controller `map-controller.js`:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

import EsriMap from "esri/Map";
import MapView from "esri/views/MapView";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        var map = new EsriMap({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: this.element,
            map: map,
            center: [-118.80500, 34.02700], // longitude, latitude
            zoom: 13
        });
    }
}
```

Originally, I tried adding ArcGIS so that it would be built using Webpack (so that the above code would work). However, I came across a compatibility issue between the ArcGIS javascript api and tailwindcss. ArcGIS would not compile because there was an issue with a call to `require('fs')`.

Rather than workaround the `require('fs')` issue (which is outside my existing experience), I opted to pull in the ArcGIS js via the CDN. So I tried to setup ArcGIS using the `external` config feature in Webpack. Here's my `webpack.js.config` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const bundleFileName = 'holly';
const dirName = 'Holly/wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: argv.mode === "production" ? "production" : "development",
        externals: {
            'esrimap': 'esri/Map',
            'mapview': 'esri/views/MapView'
        },
        entry: ['./Holly/wwwroot/js/app.js', './Holly/wwwroot/css/styles.css'],
        output: {
            filename: bundleFileName + '.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
            libraryTarget: "umd"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            }]
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: bundleFileName + '.css'
            })
        ]
    };
};
```

And this is what I did in my stimulus controller:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

import EsriMap from "esrimap";
import MapView from "mapview";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        var map = new EsriMap({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: this.element,
            map: map,
            center: [-118.80500, 34.02700], // longitude, latitude
            zoom: 13
        });
    }
}
```

However, I see the following exception in the browser:

```
TypeError: esrimap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructor
    at Controller.connect (map_controller.js:14)
    at Context.connect (context.ts:35)
    at Module.connectContextForScope (module.ts:40)
    at eval (router.ts:109)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Router.connectModule (router.ts:109)
    at Router.loadDefinition (router.ts:60)
    at eval (application.ts:51)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Application.load (application.ts:51)
```

As you might have guessed, I'm hitting the limit of my javascript/webpack knowledge. I did do a little research on the ArcGIS javascript API and whether it supports commonjs. Apparently it uses Dojo, which supports AMD. So I tried the following config instead:

```
        externals: [{
            'esrimap': {
                commonjs: 'esri/Map',
                commonjs2: 'esri/Map',
                amd: 'esri/Map'
            },
            'mapview': {
                commonjs: 'esri/views/MapView',
                commonjs2: 'esri/views/MapView',
                amd: 'esri/views/MapView'
            }
        }],
```

But I get the same error. I've read through the webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) - it's not clear to me how I should configure this. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I thought I'd address the issue with Stimulus instead.

The following is an answer to the question preceding the phrase above, ignoring everything that follows. An alternative solution that should work even though it's not an answer to your complete question.

Create a script dedicated to your blazor component, and render it or reference it in your `Pages/_host.cshtml` or `wwwroot/index.html`:

```
<script>
    window.myComponent = { 
      init: function(options) { 
        require([
          "esri/Map",
          "esri/views/MapView"
        ], function(Map, MapView) {

          var map = new Map({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
          });

          var view = new MapView({
            container: options.containerId,
            map: map,
            center: [-118.71511,34.09042],
            zoom: 11
          });

        }); // end require

       } // end init

     }; // end myComponent
  </script>
```

And call this script in you component by overriding `async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool isFirstRender)`. Only call it if `isFirstRender` is set to `true`.

You can call the script by injecting IJSRuntime and calling `await InvokeAsync("myComponent.init", "container-id")`

Something like this (untested)

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
<div id="@containerId" data-controller="map"></div>

@code {
    private string containerId = Guid.CreateGuid().ToString("n");
    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        var allowRefresh = false;

        return allowRefresh;
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool isFirstRender) {
      if (isFirstRender){ 
         await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("myComponent.init", new { containerId: containerId }) 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's very helpful. I've referred to a variation of `window.myComponent` from the Stimulus controller - which has allowed me to press on

Comment: However, I'd still like to know if I could load ArcGIS using the `import` statement via Webpack

Comment: I understand Webpack a little more now. Imports are only relevant if ArcGIS is included via Webpack - because `@arcgis/webpack-plugin` does some magic to turn CommonJS calls into AMD (so that calls remain asynchronous). The CDN references have no such magic and only support AMD. Which means that this **is** the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd document my alternate solution with Webpack. The [docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/webpack/) point you towards using Typescript. I wanted to use Webpack with ES6, here's the dependencies in my `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arcgis/webpack-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^1.3.0",
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
}
```

And here's my `webpack.config.js` file in full:

```js
const ArcGISPlugin = require("@arcgis/webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const path = require('path');
const bundleFileName = 'holly';
const dirName = 'Holly/wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: argv.mode === "production" ? "production" : "development",
        entry: ['./Holly/wwwroot/js/app.js', './Holly/wwwroot/css/styles.css'],
        output: {
            filename: bundleFileName + '.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "cache-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [ "cache-loader", {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env'
                  ],
                  plugins: [
                    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                  ]
                }
              }]
            }
          ]
        },
        resolve: {
          modules: ["node_modules/"],
          extensions: [".js"]
        },
        externals: [
            (context, request, callback) => {
              if (/pe-wasm$/.test(request)) {
                return callback(null, "amd " + request);
              }
              callback();
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            new ArcGISPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: bundleFileName + '.css'
            })
        ],
        node: {
          process: false,
          global: false,
          fs: "empty"
        }
    };
};
```

A couple of points worth noting. Firstly, the following addresses my original issue and is now documented in the `@arcgis/webpack-plugin` [readme](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md#node-globals):

```js
node: {
  process: false,
  global: false,
  fs: "empty"
}
```

With `fs: "empty"` I was able to move on to the next problem! Which was `pe-wasm` - the problem is defined (in part) in this [issue](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-webpack-plugin/issues/11). Which was great, because it lead me to [odoe/jsapi-webpack](https://github.com/odoe/jsapi-webpack) - a sample that's written in ES6! Anyway, that's where I found the following code. I'm not sure what it does exactly, but it allowed me to move on:

```js
externals: [
    (context, request, callback) => {
      if (/pe-wasm$/.test(request)) {
        return callback(null, "amd " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }
]
```

I also had to add this:

```js
resolve: {
  modules: ["node_modules/"],
  extensions: [".js"]
}
```

This allowed the wasm files to find missing dependencies! Which was fantastic, because my code finally compiled!

On a side note, because I'm using Stimulus I added Babel. Stimulus requires `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`.

At runtime, my js chunks wouldn't load. I stumbled upon the following solution:

```js
output: {
    filename: bundleFileName + '.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName),
    publicPath: '/dist/'
}
```

I needed to add `publicPath: '/dist/'` - the sub-folder where the js chunk files were being generated. This is mostly my own fault - I had configured this sub-folder long ago, not knowing that there was this consequence.

Finally, here's my revised Stimulus controller. I was missing the reference to the esri config file:

```js
import { Controller } from "stimulus";

import "../esri.config";

import EsriMap from "esri/Map";
import MapView from "esri/views/MapView";

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        var map = new EsriMap({
            basemap: "topo-vector"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
            container: this.element,
            map: map,
            center: [-118.80500, 34.02700], // longitude, latitude
            zoom: 13
        });
    }
}
```

This is the ES6 version of the config file that's in the [docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/webpack/):

```js
import esriConfig from "esri/config";

const DEFAULT_WORKER_URL = "https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/";
const DEFAULT_LOADER_URL = `${DEFAULT_WORKER_URL}dojo/dojo-lite.js`;

esriConfig.workers.loaderUrl = DEFAULT_LOADER_URL;
esriConfig.workers.loaderConfig = {
  baseUrl: `${DEFAULT_WORKER_URL}dojo`,
  packages: [
    { name: "esri", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "esri" },
    { name: "dojo", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "dojo" },
    { name: "dojox", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "dojox" },
    { name: "dijit", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "dijit" },
    { name: "dstore", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "dstore" },
    { name: "moment", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "moment" },
    { name: "@dojo", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "@dojo" },
    {
      name: "cldrjs",
      location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "cldrjs",
      main: "dist/cldr"
    },
    {
      name: "globalize",
      location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "globalize",
      main: "dist/globalize"
    },
    {
      name: "maquette",
      location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "maquette",
      main: "dist/maquette.umd"
    },
    {
      name: "maquette-css-transitions",
      location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "maquette-css-transitions",
      main: "dist/maquette-css-transitions.umd"
    },
    {
      name: "maquette-jsx",
      location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "maquette-jsx",
      main: "dist/maquette-jsx.umd"
    },
    { name: "tslib", location: DEFAULT_WORKER_URL + "tslib", main: "tslib" }
  ]
};
```

I think that covers everything. Hopefully it's useful to someone!

Comment: It's useful, but it isn't really clear (at least to me) why / what is being done. What you be against specifying in 20 words or less the overarching strategy? (thank you for documenting your answer btw)

Comment: So originally I wanted to serve the Javascript for our ArcGIS map from our server (which is why I was avoiding the CDN link. I also wanted write code for ArcGIS Javascript using ES6. Deploying ArcGIS Javascript with Webpack allowed me to do both

Comment: The steps listed above are mainly about two things - how to configure webpack and workarounds to make ArcGIS work with webpack modules (instead of AMD modules)

Comment: However, building ArcGIS with webpack increased the build/deployment time significantly. The workarounds listed above are numerous. In the end I decided it was easier to stick with ES5 to avoid extended build times

Comment: One final note, I had intended to use Stimulus js - to help isolate my javascript code (another motivator for using ArcGIS with webpack). Sticking with ES5 (at the time) I ended up moving away from this idea too. Now there's more support for ES6 in modern browsers, I may revisit/investigate the use of Stimulus with Blazor

Comment: if build time is a problem, I would highly recommend esbuild or a tool which leverages ebsuild under the hood. build time for me has been an order of magnitude faster. i'm in the same situation as yourself. i need to modularize an IIFE function to use with stimulus

Comment: Yes. I agree. We're using the new Tailwind JIT and that has let me strip out webpack. The next step is esbuild!